# How do I set up the cron environment to run a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, cron

I have a Ruby script on a Linode VM that I'd like to run every minute.

When I run the ruby script manually via the command line, it runs perfectly.  But when the cron runs the file, it throws a strange error:

```
undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
```

["/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1060:in `request'", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httparty-0.7.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:69:in`perform'", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httparty-0.7.3/lib/httparty.rb:394:in `perform_request'", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httparty-0.7.3/lib/httparty.rb:346:in`get'", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httparty-0.7.3/lib/httparty.rb:426

I've been investigating this problem and it seems as if it has something to do with the stripped down environment that cron runs the script in.

Do I need to source my Ruby environment in the crontab file?  If so, what exactly do I need?

Here's my env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

which ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When cron runs scripts, it does not inherit your environment. Usually, the easiest thing to do is write a wrapper shell script that sources whatever you need and then calls your ruby script.

For example, most of my cron scripts look something like

```
#!/bin/sh

. ${HOME}/.bashrc

# Do Stuff - here is where you would call your ruby script
```

Comment: Matt, can you give me an example? I tried this method but was not sure how to source my env / what I need to source.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I've added an edit with a pseudo-example - the file you source would depend on what shell you use.

Comment: What do you mean "what shell you use"?  Sorry, total linux noob here.  It's ubuntu on a Linode vm with nothing but ruby/rubygems installed.